# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed - while using servlet

Tags: java, html, database, tomcat, servlets

My code is to use java servlets and JDBC to store and retrieve the information from a database. There is no error in the IDE the program is running but, the rows aren't inserted into the database and an error occurred in the firefox browser.

**The following code is from the SERVLET file**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletRegister extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter("text/html");
        
        String uname = req.getParameter("uname");
        String passwd = req.getParameter("passwd");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        int phno = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("phno"));
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hack","root","");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into student values(?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,uname);
            ps.setString(2,passwd);
            ps.setString(3, email);
            ps.setInt(4, phno);
            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0)
                out.print("Registerd Successfully");
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**The following code is from HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="register">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter User Name: <input type="text" name="uname"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Password: <input type="password" name="passwd"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Phone.no: <input type="number" name="phno" min="6000000000" max="9999999999"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="reset"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The following code is from web.xml file**

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.hacker.ServletRegister</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**The Error is:** 
[Error obtained in firefox browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55lu6.png)

Comment: Your form is sending the request with the default method which is `GET` since you haven't specified it to do a `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postman to send a POST request to your server, or change doPost to doGet

Answer (score 0):

In HTML file  tag you did not mention the method= "post" So its taking the value by default "get" request.